# How to make my CSS @keyframes animation on SVG elements smoother in Firefox and less resource-intensive?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

[This animation](https://codepen.io/lucasket/pen/VwYYRby) induces high CPU usage in every browser, but is a lot smoother in Chromium. How can I optimize its execution? Here's the -pretty simple- SCSS:

```
@keyframes laptop {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0.8rem) rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0.8rem) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes phone {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0.8rem) rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(0.8rem) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.header {
  &__laptop {
    animation: laptop 12s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
  }

  &__phone {
    animation: phone 8s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the animations are looping infinitely, they are naturally resource intensive.

You can trick the CPU into accelerating the animation (and thus reducing the burden) by making the amination 3d. You could, for example, add `translateZ(0)` to the keyframes to achieve this.

You might do something like:

```
 @keyframes laptop {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0.8rem) translateZ(0) rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0.8rem) translateZ(0) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes phone {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0.8rem) translateZ(0) rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg) translateX(0.8rem) translateZ(0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.header {
  &__laptop {
    animation: laptop 12s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
  }

  &__phone {
    animation: phone 8s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did read that this hack supposedly enhanced performances, but it doesn't look like it either looking at my task manager or at the Firefox rendering which is still pretty "choppy"